# Angular Timeout Queue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular service that makes an Web API call out to retrieve my search results.  The problem I'm having is the angular controller & UI is set up in a way that allows the search to be called multiple times per second causing the service to be queued up.  I tried resolving/defer the http call when a new one comes in but it doesnt seem like the best solution.  I would rather queue up all the search calls I get within a certain time period and then only execute the last one.  Any ideas on how I could do that?

Comment: With just your post to go on, this is currently a very broad question. Please add a [mcve] that represents your situation and be specific about where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

```
timeout(function(){
   var length = queue.length
   var item = queue[length - 1];
   queue.splice(0, length);
   processItem(item);
} , <yourtime:number>)
```

keep adding your requests to the queue. and add the processing logic to the `processItem` function. 
this might do the needful

*note - please consider this as a pseudo code. might have compilations errors

 
Alternatively you can just create a bool variable which is referred every time a request is about to be made and done make the request till its true. Somethign like this

```
function processItem(item){
 if(process){
   process = false;
  //YOUR ACTUAL PROCESSING CODE
 }
}

$timeout(function(){
 process = true;
}, <yourtime in milli seconds>)
```